# App Registration in AD doesn't show in Apps Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I created a Azure Active Directory via the Azure portal. Then, I registered an app in it. I can configure it, add permissions and the like via the azure portal. But the same app I created, I don't see on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ 
Shouldn't I be able to see and configure the app I made in AD at that portal, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apps that appear in the Application Registration Portal are the ones where you are explicitly marked as an owner of the application. This is in contrast to the apps that appear in the Azure Portal which are all the applications registered in your tenant, independent of whether or not your are an owner.

If you are a normal user, and you create an application in the Azure Portal, you should see your application appear in a section called "Azure AD only applications"

[image]

Here is the owner information for "Email Scraper" from the Azure Portal.
[image]

However, if you are a Tenant Administrator and you create an application, you will **not** be marked as an owner of the application. Implicitly, Tenant Administrators are owners of all objects in the directory, and to reduce the object quota generated by admins, these explicit links are not created.

Here is an example of an app I created where I am the Tenant Administrator:
[image]

Therefore, you probably do not see your application in the App Registration Portal because you are not marked as an Owner of the application, probably because you are an Administrator who created the app, or you did not create the app to begin with. You can remedy this by simply adding yourself to the owner list in the Azure Portal.

Let me know if this helps!